# centos virtual machine not registering with intranet dns server

Tags: networking, centos, virtualbox, dns, virtual-machine

When I am creating a Ubuntu virtual machine on virtual box it automatically registered with DNS server in my intranet network, it has both intranet IP and domain name. When creating CentOS virtual machine on virtual box it does not registered with DNS server it has intranet IP but don't have domain name.

How to make CentOS virtual machine automatically registered with DNS server line Ubuntu virtual machine.

What are the things I want to do to create domain name in intranet network.

Comment: What is your DNS system managed by? Active Directory?